# objectify ofy().load() by String Id works locally, throws NotFoundException on appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have the following entity:

```
public class Subscription {
    @Id
    String orderName;
        .....
    transient ArrayList<Long> plantsOrderIds;

    int qty;
    @Load
    transient Ref<SubscriptionPlan> subscriptionPlan;
        ......
        [Getters/ Setters] 
        ........
}
```

And i have this function to get Subscription by orderName.

```
public Subscription getSubscription(String orderName) {
    return ofy().load().type(Subscription.class).id(orderName).safe();
}

Subscription sub = getSubscription("foo"); // returns the Subscription running locally, and throws NotFoundException when deployed on appengine.
```

I updated the function to the following but still same behavior:

```
public Subscription getSubscription(String orderName) {
    Key<Subscription> key = Key.create(Subscription.class, orderName);
    return ofy().load().key(key).safe();
}
```

Any suggestions what is causing the issue, or am i missing something?

Comment: I have already posted the question in their google group btw: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/l5LCwKsWCpQ

Comment: As responded - there is nothing wrong with this code. There is a mismatch between what you're saving and what you're trying to load. Look at your save code.

Comment: You are totally correct, there was a migration mismatch the entity was initially saved with Long id, then changed to String id, with the same value.